# How to replace a search word in VIM using "c"?

Tags: vim

I have strings in the following way in VIM:

```cpp
SetDynamicFrictionDoesNothingIfProvidedArgumentIsInvalid
SetDynamicFrictionCreatesCollidableIfItDoesNotExist
```

**Without** doing a search and replace (i.e `:%s/DynamicFriction/Restitution`), I want to be able to replace the word "DynamicFriction" with "Restitution." I really like using the `c` command in VIM to do remove and enter edit mode in one command because I can combine this with search and easily go through lines and decide what I want to update.

How can I achieve this? I tried the following but it did not work:

```
Note that "+" means combining in this context, not a VIM thing

c + /DynamicFriction/e
```

But this goes to the end of the whole word and basically removes the entire line. How can I make it so that, only the "DynamicFriction" is removed.

Comment: Did you know that you can use search/replace interactively? `:%s/foo/bar/c` (`c` for "confirm")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `c` is an operator.
2. An operator "operates" on a *motion*.

`DynamicFriction` being pretty much a random string found within another, larger, random string, you can't really expect it to be covered by an existing built-in motion.

Moreover…

- `c/pattern<CR>` would change *all the text* from the cursor *to* the next match,
- `c/pattern/e<CR>` would do the same but including the match.

so you can't expect that approach yield anything useful either.

If you *really* don't want to use a substitution for this—which is a shame because it is by far the best method—you can use `:help gn` in two steps.

1. Search for your pattern with:

   ```
   /DynamicFriction<CR>
   ```
2. Change the current match (or next match if the cursor is not on a match) with:

   ```
   cgnRestitution<Esc>
   ```

Note that `cgn` is an interesting operator+motion combo that a) uses a very special motion: "jump to next match unless already on a match *and visually select it*"), and b) is repeatable with `.`. This makes that kind of things possible:

```
/DynamicFriction<CR>    " search for pattern
cgnRestitution<Esc>     " change match
.                       " repeat change
.                       " etc.
```

[image: cgn]